# Ionic OAuth integration

Tags: typescript, oauth, ionic3

I googled a lot about OAuth1.0 integration with my ionic app. I didn't get any information which i am looked for. Can anybody share some example or idea about how to integrate it. I have a server and need to send request through http OAuth and get the response as JSON data.

I am using Ionic 3 with angular in my application.

It is something similar like, for example in javascript we can use JSOAuth-1.3.6.js file will do all the above things.

Thanks
Krishmtech